# How to set context data back to the jobExecutionContext if get data from @Value("#{jobExecutionContext}")?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

From [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding), it shows how to pass in the context data

```
@JobScope
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['input.name']}") String name) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Foo>()
            .name("flatFileItemReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(name))
            ...
}
```

I change `@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['input.name']}") String name` to `@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") Map<String, Object> context`, I would like to pass in an object and put extra data in the step `context.put("aa","bb)`, then pass these new data to the next step. But an exception was thrown because the `context` object is an UnmodifiableMap.

Those tutorials only mention how to get the data, but don't show how to set data.

Update 1:
If I have a @SteopScope ItemWriter\ItemReader\ItemProcessor,
The only possible way to pass in context data is to use constructor injection?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to pass in an object and put extra data in the step context.put("aa","bb), then pass these new data to the next step.

Passing data between steps is explained in the this section: [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps). You can inject the step execution in the required component to get access to the execution context. Then you can set the attribute you want to pass as needed.

Comment: In your provided link,  If I add @StepScope to  RetrievingItemWriter
The method that has `@BeforeStep` is not going to be invoked.

Comment: It should, when the component is declared as a bean (So that Spring Batch introspects the annotation and creates the proxy).